# How do I fix the Invalid key error that appears while using Git Config Command?

Tags: git, http-proxy

I am trying to configure proxy using the Git Config command. However it constantly throws the invalid key error.

`$ git config https.proxy https://id1234:testpwd2020@proxy:8080`

`error: invalid key: https.proxy https://id1234:testpwd2020@proxy:8080`

Any idea how to fix this issue.

Comment: Is `<br/>` part of the command?

Comment: No. I removed it. Its just ``git config https.proxy https://id1234:testpwd2020@proxy:8080``

Comment: `http.proxy` instead of `https.proxy` is a valid key.

Comment: No I get the same error for both http.proxy as well as https.proxy.

Comment: Is there any invisible space characters between `https.proxy` and `https://id1234:testpwd2020@proxy:8080`, in case you copied the command from some web? `http.proxy` and `hppts.proxy` should both succeed for `git config` except that `https.proxy` is not pre-defined in `git config`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. you were right. I had copied the command from web and it looks like it had some invisible characters.

It worked when I typed the command manually myself. Thanks for your help.